# $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2^{n^3}}{n!5^{n^2}-n^n}$ without special means

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2^{n^3}}{n!5^{n^2}-n^n}=+\infty$$
>
> without using l'Hôpitals rule or any special means.

My first attempts were to use inequalities to approximate $n!$ and $n^n$ but I am really unsure what to do with $2^{n^3}$ and $5^{n^3}$. Any specific hints on how to transform this fraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to estimate the denominator from above. For example $n! \le n^n \le (2^{n})^n = 2^{(n^2)}$. The basic idea is that $2^{(n^3)}$ is "so large" that you have much place to be generous with your estimations.

Comment: My results are always converging to 0 like $1/n!$ or $1/(5^{n^2}-1)$. Do you know what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Oh I did some stupid mistakes - I have been able to get the desired result!